# Mixed time scales for org mode repeated habits

Tags: org-mode, org-habit

I'm trying to set-up an `org-mode` habit (i.e., "STYLE" property = "habit") to repeat at a maximum of one month, on the first of the month, and a minimum of one month and five days (the fifth of the month). Is it possible to achieve something like this, something like `SCHEDULED: <2015-05-01 Fri +1m/1m5d>`? Emacs doesn't see the "`5d`" portion in this script though--it only recognizes the "`+1m/1m`" and subsequently throws an error.

Is there a syntax that enables Emacs to handle this mixed time scale?